# Как использовать ChosenInlineResultHandler в Python Telegram Bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Здравствуйте.

Использую [python-telegram-bot](http://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io)

Не понимаю, как правильно обрабатывать `InlineKeyboardButton`.

```
def start(bot, update):

    currencies = [currency for currency in API().get_currencies()]    

    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("{}".format(c), callback_data='{}'.format(c))] for c in currencies]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    update.message.reply_text('Select the currency you want to exchange:', reply_markup=reply_markup)


updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
```

Теперь, мне нужно обработать выбор, передав его в другую функцию, при помощи, `ChosenInlineResultHandler`, но я не понимаю, как это сделать.

Answer (score 3):

нужно обработать **InlineKeyboard** или **InlineQuery** ?

пример [InlineKeyboard](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/inlinekeyboard.py)

пример [InlineQuery](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/inlinebot.py)

полностью рабочие. для `InlineQuery` необходимо включить `Inline` режим для своего бота.

Инициализировать метод `ChosenInlineResultHandler` можно используя пример `InlineQuery` из официальной документации.
Когда пользователь вызает `Inline` режим бота из любого чата, например **@youtube fun** бот обрабатывает ввод аргументов и получет актуальный набор данных:

```
{'inline_query':{
    'query': u'USER_MESSAGE_TEXT', 'offset': u'',    // введенный текст
        'from': {'username': u'USERNAME',
                'first_name': u'NAME',
                'id': 000000000,
                'language_code': u'en-US'},           // информация о пользователе
    'id': u'1100110001010010001'},                    // ID текущего Inline запроса
'update_id': 000000000}                               // ID текущего обновления
```

теперь мы можем вызвать `ChosenInlineResultHandler`:

```
ChosenInlineResult(
    result_id=update.inline_query.id,
    from_user=update.inline_query.from_user,
    query=update.inline_query)
```

в Python следует использовать `from_user` вместо `from`.

Так же, можно исользовать объект `Update` вызвав метод `Update.de_json()` передавая в него `update_id` и текущего бота `bot`.
В каждом методе есть описание как правильно его вызывать.